# Finding eigenvalues and eigenvector from a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

**Problem:**

Let *T*: $ℝ^3$ → $ℝ^3$ be a linear transformation for which

$$
T\left(
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    -2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\right)=\begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
0 \\
6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
T\left(
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\
    1 \\
    -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\right)=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\
-1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

(a) From the above information, find two eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors.

(b) If det(*T*) = 6, what is the third eigenvalue of *T*?

(c) Is it possible that *T* is a stochastic matrix? Why or why not?

---

So I am pretty sure that I would be able to figure out the answers for part b and c however I am stuck on part a. I can't seem to think of the link between the eigenvalues/vectors and am just completely stumped and I'm can't go anywhere. I'm pretty sure for part b I could use the determinant and trace to find the eigenvalue, and for part C it would depend on the three eigenvectors/values. If it has 1 for a eigenvalue and if the eigenvalues are complex numbers they must come in complex conjugates otherwise if 1 is an eigenvalue it is possible that it is a stochastic matrix.

Comment: You say $T:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, but the vectors are $3$-tuples.  Are you sure this is right?

Comment: No it was supposed to be 3, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that$$
T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\    0 \\    -2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\right)=(-3)\times\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\-2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$and that$$
T\left(    \begin{bmatrix}    2 \\    1 \\    -1 \\    \end{bmatrix}
\right)=(-1)\times\begin{bmatrix}2 \\1 \\-1 \\\end{bmatrix}.$$Doesn't this give you a clue about the eigenvalues of $T$?

Comment: so then that would mean two of my eigenvalues are just -3 and -1?

Comment: Indeed, it means that.

Comment: Well sadly that was much easier than I expected, thank you much.